# How to stop the first processor of the flow within processor group in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

My requirement is to stop the first processor of the flow in a particular processor group using NIFI REST API.

So in 1st invoke http processor using GET method and HTTP URL is http://10.64.4.55:31020/nifi-api/processors/436bce7b-1e39-3a6c-ad40-3ae05cd43845. processor id of first processor of the flow is 436bce7b-1e39-3a6c-ad40-3ae05cd43845.

Next in evaluate JSON path processor I'm mapping the attributes version as $.revision.version and ClientID as $.revision.clientId .

Next in replace text processor , for replacement value I'm giving

```json
{
  "revision": {
    "ClientID": ${ClientID},
    "version": ${version}
  },
  "component": {
    "id": "436bce7b-1e39-3a6c-ad40-3ae05cd43845",
    "state": "STOPPED"
  }
}
```

Then connecting to next invoke HTTP processor with PUT method and URL as http://10.64.4.55:31020/nifi-api/processors/436bce7b-1e39-3a6c-ad40-3ae05cd43845.

But I'm unable to stop the processor. this process as worked using postman. but through NIFI, I'm unable to achieve it. getting invoke HTTP body response is as

`Message body is malformed. Unable to map into expected format.`